# ros::Time::now() always return wall time in c++

Tags: ros, c++, time, static-transform-publisher, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I have a very frustrating problem using Ros Hydro on ubuntu 12.04.
I have a Gazebo Simulation posting telemetry data and I use this in a node to create a tf-tree for the simulation.

Now I tried to combine my tf-tree with some static transform publishers and noticed that my transform from the c++ node which subscribes to the telemetry is using wall time.
The statics transform publishers are using simulation time.

I searched the web, set use_sim_time to true and tried some other things but ros::Time::now() in my c++ code always returns wall time, while the static transform publisher use simulation time!
This makes it impossible to use the transform together.

use_sime_time is set before launching any nodes, but my node launches before the /clock topic is available, looking into this next.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187426/ros::time::now()-always-return-wall-time-in-c++/) by [proprentnerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/19815/proprentnerl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

use_sim_time was needed but lead to another problem. The main node was waiting for a service from a python node... when using use_sim_time the main node wouldn't detect the service as long as the /clock service was nit published...
Our main node starts the simulation with the /clock service, so doing this first before waiting for the python node service fixed the problem...
It seems that python nodes become unresponsive when use_sim_time is activated but no /clock topic is published even when they don't need ans ros::Time functions.

---

Originally posted by [proprentnerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/19815/proprentnerl/) with karma: 26 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you setting `use_sim_time` before starting the node in questions? Can you check if your node subscribes to the `/clock` topic?

Please update your question with this information.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [proprentnerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/19815/proprentnerl/) on 2014-07-22**:
Yes use_sim_time is set before starting the node, it seems that my node starts before the /clock topic is available and than continues to use wall time instead of switching to simulation time. I will try waiting for the /clock topic before calling ros::Time::now() in my node.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-22**:
I believe ros::Time has an explicit method to wait for the simulated clock to be initialized.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-22**:
See [ros::Time::waitForValid()](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Time.html#ab61825bb028f8c10c5e94aeca32bbfda)

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-07-23**:
@proprentnerl: I don't think your theory is correct. If use_sim_time is set, ros::Time::now() will return 0 until it receives the first /clock message, not walltime. This is also the condition that waitForValid() checks for, so that won't fix your problem.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-07-23**:
The rospy implementation of tf has some horrible hacks (and bugs) involving walltime, but you mentioned using roscpp, so my guess is that @demmeln is right: your node is started before use_sim_time is set.